# Hide the copy paste pop that comes up when user select text cordova.

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, cordova

i want user to select the text but i don't want to show the default copy paste option to user. -webkit-touch-callout:none doesn't work for android. Any plugin in cordova or any css or any other jquery functionality which need to implement

Note:User can select text but default copy paste menu should show up. If we can show custom menu that is also fine

Answer (score 0):

Use this in order to avoid  pasting:

```
<input type="text" onpaste="return false;">
```

Note: Although the onpaste event is supported by all HTML elements, it is not actually possible to paste some content in, for example, a `<p>` element, UNLESS the element has set contenteditable to "true" (See "More Examples" below).

Comment: the text is inside div not in any input or textarea